# fill list of list by summing rows in each data frame in all combinations

Tags: r, list, loops

I have 4 data frames saved as .csv files or .txt (df1.csv,df2.csv,df3.txt,df4.txt).
I would like to sum all the rows of df1 with df3 and df4 and of df2 with df3 and df4 in a loop. I would like to store the results in two separate sublists (one for df1 and one for df2) of a main list.

Example:

```
df1      df3
colA    colA
5        1
1        4
3        1

df2     df4
colA    colA
0        0
2        0
1        9
```

Output:

I would like to have a list_ALL which contains listDF1 with the results of the sum of df1 with df3 and df4 and a listDF2 which contains results of df2 with df3 and df4

```
LISTDF1


 df5   df6
   
 colA   colA
  6      5
  5      1
  4      12

LISTDF2


  df7   df8

  colA  colA
   1    0
   6    2
   2    10


list_ALL<-list()

files.csv<-list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
files.txt<-list.files(pattern = "*.txt")
for (i in 1:length(files.csv)) {
  list_ALL[[i]]<-list()
}
names(listALL)<-files.csv

for (i in 1:length(files.csv))
  for (j in 1:length(files.txt))
    {{ list_ALL[[i]][[j]] <- rowSums([[i]][[j]])}}
```

I tried this however, only the first one of the sublist gets filled up.

Comment: wouldn't it make a lot more sense to have 1 & 2 in one list and 3 & 4 in a second?

what you are trying to do here is unnecessarily complicated. you just want to do 1+3/4 and 2+3/4 which can be easily done. the way you group 1 and 3 and 2 and 4 makes this nearly impossible without adding some if statement which throws out (or at least complicates) a general solution

Comment: Actually, what I have is 50 csv files and 50 txt files which I want to compare. I would like to have a loop which compares each single csv file against each single txt file, the csv files belong to a type of data and the txt files belong to another type of data, that's why I would like two have a list of list

Comment: @D.J what would it be a general solution?

Comment: yes that is what i assumed - that's exactly my point. in the input you order 1,3 / 2,4 which makes little sense. the results however are ordered in a way that does make sense 5,6 /7,8. if your files are in order from the get go like 1,2 / 3,4 it would be much easier to work with

Comment: any logic that does the following: 
1) take list entry 1 of list1 and sum it up with list entry 1 of list2.  - 
2) take list entry 2 of list1 and sum it up with list entry 1 of list2.  - 
3) take list entry 2 of list1 and sum it up with list entry 1 of list2   - 
4) take list entry 2 of list1 and sum it up with list entry 2 of list2 -
----
you can then expand this to as many lists as you like

Comment: yes, I did not specify but I have df1 and df2 in a list

Comment: based on that logic, how a loop should be written?

Comment: can you give example, please?

Comment: you can post it as solution

Comment: ok I tried that, actually, it is something similar to what I wrote, but I get this error:

Comment: Warning messages:
1: In 1:seq_along(files) :
  numerical expression has 38 elements: only the first used

Comment: only the first list gets filled up

Comment: yes, i didn't update the saving process in my answer... what i am not sure about is how you are going to deal with 50 lists - you would need 50 for statements which seems unrealistic. this only works if you have 2 lists - no matter how long. so i am not sure this is a viable answer outside of your question where it works just fine. but you would have to define all your interoperations anyway. interesting problem - maybe ask a new question regarding this. i only solved the problem of saving all results in the correct order for the given data.

Comment: yeah that's my problem, I have to write 50 for statements and I was wondering how to do by writing only one for loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242808/discussion-between-d-j-and-paolo-lorenzini).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
lst1 <- list(df1<-c(5,1,3), df2<-c(0,2,1))

lst2 <- list(df3<-c(1,4,1), df4<-c(0,0,9))

res_lst <- list()
for(i in seq_along(lst1)){
  for(j in seq_along(lst2)){
       res <- lst1[[i]]+lst2[[j]]
       res_lst <- append(res_lst, list(res))
  }
}

splt_lst <- split(x = res_lst, f = rep(1:2, each=2))


$`1`
$`1`[[1]]
[1] 6 5 4

$`1`[[2]]
[1]  5  1 12


$`2`
$`2`[[1]]
[1] 1 6 2

$`2`[[2]]
[1]  0  2 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```r
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(colA = sample(1:10, 3))
df2 <- data.frame(colA = sample(1:10, 3))
df3 <- data.frame(colA = sample(1:10, 3))
df4 <- data.frame(colA = sample(1:10, 3))

lapply(list(df1, df2), 
       \(x) asplit(sapply(list(df3, df4), \(y) rowSums(cbind(x,y))), 2)) 

#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [1]  8 14  8
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]]
#> [1]  9 19  4
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]][[1]]
#> [1]  7 10  9
#> 
#> [[2]][[2]]
#> [1]  8 15  5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (j in 1:length(files))
  {
    cog_out_dat[[j]]<- lapply(meta_exp_dat,function(df) try(read_outcome_data(
      snps = df$SNP,
      filename = files[[j]],
      gene_col = "anno",
      sep = " ",
      chr_col = "CHR",
      pos_col = "BP",
      snp_col = "SNP",
      beta_col = "BETA",
      se_col = "SE",
      effect_allele_col = "ALLELE1",
      other_allele_col = "ALLELE0",
      eaf_col = "EAF",
      pval_col = "P",
      phenotype_col = "DATA"
    )))
  }
```